# How to test all sample combinations for significant differences?

Tags: r, testing, combinations, significance

I'm analyzing a dataset of 9 plots in R and want to compare them with each other. My responding variables are not normally distributed.

Now my question:

There are 9+8+7+...+2+1=45 pair-combinations to be tested. Can R do this automatically? If yes, how? 
My wish-output would be a box-whisker plot with my 9 plots on the x-axis, the responding variable on the y-axis and lowercase letters above the plots to indicate significant differences.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Well, first you have to decide which test to use. You could transform your variables in order to use a parametric test or you could use a non-parametric test. Then you'd need to decide how you want to adjust for alpha error inflation. Then you could use the `combn` or `outer` functions for the pairwise comparisons. Or, possibly, you can use package multcomp. Answer the statistical questions and we can help you with the implementation.

Comment: Well, I guess a Bonferroni-corrected MW-U-Test should be the appropriate choice in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should get you started:

```
#some data
x <- rlnorm(100, mean=1:4)
DF <- data.frame(x=x, g=c("a", "b", "c", "d"), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

#pairwise Mann-Whitney-U-test
pairwise.wilcox.test(DF$x, DF$g, p.adjust.method = "bonferroni")

#   Pairwise comparisons using Wilcoxon rank sum test 
#
#data:  DF$x and DF$g 
#
#  a       b       c     
#b 0.0016  -       -     
#c 6.3e-09 0.0020  -     
#d 1.9e-13 2.0e-08 0.1823
#
#P value adjustment method: bonferroni
```

Comment: Very good answer, thank you very much!

Do you have any idea, how to efficiently merge these results into distinct groups, like (a),(b),(ab)?

Comment: @Hav0k Definitely read the Details of `?p.adjust`, it includes "There seems no reason to use the unmodified Bonferroni correction because it is dominated by Holm's method".